# Problems configuring nginx for a flask site

Tags: python, nginx

I am having trouble getting nginx to serve the small flask site I am working on.  I followed some tutorials from Digital Ocean, and I get it mostly right, but here is the problem:

In my /etc/nginx/sites-available/xproject configuration file, my server block has `listen 80` as well as `server_name www.mydomainname.com server_ip_address;`

When I launch a browser and go to my IP address or www.mydomainname.com, I get "Welcome to nginx!"

Now, if I change the server block to listen on port 8080 (or another port) it works properly and browsing to  www.mydomainname.com:8080 or my IP address with that port displays the page I want.  But I want it to load properly on the default port 80.

Based on a bit of reading, it sounds like nginx's default configuration file listens on port 80, and that it must be overriding my server block above.  But I have removed the nginx default configuration filesfrom /etc/nginx/sites-enabled and sites-available and restarted the nginx server and still have the same issue.  Can anyone explain where this default is being set and how to change it?

I am working with Ubuntu 12.04 on a linode.

Thank you for any tips or suggestions.

EDIT: Here is my nginx.conf file from /etc/nginx/

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-    javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

...and here is my default file from /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/:

```
# You may add here your
# server {
#   ...
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file

##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

server {
    #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to index.html
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
        # For example, return an error code
        #return 418;
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #   fastcgi_index index.php;
    #   include fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#   listen 8000;
#   listen somename:8080;
#   server_name somename alias another.alias;
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
#   }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#   listen 443;
#   server_name localhost;
#
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   ssl on;
#   ssl_certificate cert.pem;
#   ssl_certificate_key cert.key;
#
#   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
#
#   ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
#   ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
#   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
#   }
#}
```

Note: I did move the file out of sites-enabled and sites-available.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your main nginx config at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` as well as your `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

Answer (score 0):

Nginx serves static files and it cannot execute and host Python applications. You should use uWSGI or something similar. I preferably use Gunicorn.

Comment: I do use uwsgi, and when I set the port to 8080, I am able to view my flask site the way I expect.  It is only when I try to use port 80 that I fail.

Comment: In that case, you can use proxy_pass. Something like:

location / {
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        break;
    }
}

Comment: Alright, tampering with the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default did not work.  But I do have it up and running now, so for those having this problem: simply remove default from the sites-enabled folder and save it somewhere else.  I thought I had tried that right at the start of all this, but now it actually works....

Answer (score 0):

You can use gunicorn to run your flask app behind reverse proxy of nignx. The conf might be like below:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name foo.xxoo.com;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    access_log /home/web/caimaoy/log/access.log;
    error_log /home/web/caimaoy/log/error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host; 
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```